# Добавить данные в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу завершить задачу в Hyperskill...

Есть пустой словарь ирисов, в него надо добавить содержимое о видах с помощью функции.

Обязательные параметры на входе функции `id_n`, `species`, `petal_length` и `petal_width`, могут быть и дополнительные параметры.

Например, после первого вызова функции `add_iris(0, 'Iris versicolor', 4.0, 1.3, petal_hue='pale lilac')` словарь iris будет выглядеть следующим образом

`{0: {'species': 'Iris versicolor', 'petal_length': 4.0, 'petal_width': 1.3, 'petal_hue': 'pale lilac'}}`

Вот моя функция:

```
def add_iris(id_n, species, petal_length, petal_width, **kwargs):
    flower = {id_n:
                 {'species': species,
                  'petal_length': petal_length,
                  'petal_width': petal_width,
                 }
             }
    if kwargs:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            flower[id_n].update({key: value})
    iris.update(flower)
    return iris
```

тестовые даные таковы: `0 Iris_virginica 4.601842275930201 0.49692223898863797`

вывод следущий: `{0: {'species': 'Iris_virginica', 'petal_length': 4.601842275930201, 'petal_width': 0.49692223898863797}}`

вывод для примера из условия: `{0: {'species': 'Iris versicolor', 'petal_length': 4.0, 'petal_width': 1.3, 'petal_hue': 'pale lilac'}}`

Что не так в результате работы моей функции? Может ее можно подругому написать (мне другие идеи в голову не идут)?

Comment: В чём заключается проблема? Всё работает. Разве что можно упростить тело функции до: `iris[id_n] = {'species': species, 'petal_length': petal_length, petal_width': petal_width, **kwargs}`.

Comment: facehugger, проблема заключается в том, что грейдер выдает "Wrong answer". Кураторы и пользователи молчат

Comment: Проблема решена! Строку **iris.update(flower)** перенёс в **return** и решение прошло